# requestAccessForMediaType completion block working very slow

Tags: ios

I am trying to pop camera on click of Ok in requestAccessForMediaType camera access dialog box but the camera opens up very late.

Comment: Make sure you are dispatching any events that affect the UI (such as opening the camera via) on the main queue

Comment: Improve your Quetion

Comment: Can you add some description or put up some code to clarify?